# Why are terminal calls failing in my Mac Electron application?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

*(I'm new to Electron and Mac, so treat me like I've 5 years old, please)*

I have an Electron (15.1.2) application packaged with electron-builder (22.13.1). I need to run some terminal calls, so I'm using child-process (1.0.2)

```
const {exec} = require("child_process");
    
exec("node -v" , (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(error, stdout, stderr)
});
```

When authoring the application in Visual Studio Code and running the code on Mac and Windows, this works fine, stdout returns "`v15.14.0`" but once I package with electron-bundler and run the .app file I get "`NODE Error command failed: node -v /bin/sh: node: command not found`" Other commands are returning `null`.

Why are these calls failing in the Mac .app ?
Running the .exe on Windows, everything is fine.

I'm not sure what a person would need to know to help me, please ask any questions and I'll try to provide the answer.

Comment: For testing purposes, can you put full path of node like `/usr/local/bin/node -v`, to see what you can get ?

Comment: That worked, I got "NODE null v15.14.0".  Thanks @Philippe